# Dynamo Local from Node-aws: all operations fail "Cannot do operations on a non-existent table"

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I have a local dynamo-db running. I have set up my tables using the JavaScript console and they list OK from there.

I can also put and get items to my tables from the JavaScript console:

```
var params = { TableName:"environmentId", Item: { environmentId: {"S":"a4fe1736-98cf-4560-bcf4-cc927730dd1b"} }};
dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log("put : err was " + JSON.stringify(err) + " and data is " + JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

prints `put : err was null and data is {}` which I'm assuming is "success" because

```
params = { "Key":{"environmentId":{"S":"a4fe1736-98cf-45e0-bcf4-cc927730dd1b"}},"TableName":"environmentId"}
dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log("get : err was " + JSON.stringify(err) + " and data is " + JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

prints `get : err was null and data is {"Item":{"environmentId":{"S":"a4fe1736-98cf-45e0-bcf4-cc927730dd1b"}}}` i.e. it retrieves the object I just put to the table.

However, if it fire up the node REPL and type:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath("./config/credentials.js");
endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint("http://localhost:8000");
var dynamoOpts = {apiVersion: '2012-08-10', 'endpoint':endpoint};
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB(dynamoOpts);
var params = { TableName:"environmentId", Item: { environmentId: {"S":"a4fe1736-98cf-4560-bcf4-cc927730dd1b"} }};
dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log("put : err was " + JSON.stringify(err) + " and data is " + JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

I get a resource not found error:

```
{ "message":"Cannot do operations on a non-existent table",
    "code":"ResourceNotFoundException",
    "time":"2015-04 10T10:01:26.319Z",
    "statusCode":400,
    "retryable":false,
    "retryDelay":0
}
```

The ASW.request object returned from the putCommand has the correct    endpoint:

```
{ protocol: 'http:',
    host: 'localhost:8000',
    port: 8000,
    hostname: 'localhost',
    pathname: '/',
    // etc.
```

The same thing happens from my Node app however the same code connecting to the real AWS hosted dynamo works.

Comment: this could be tagged with other languages too, same behavior for .net.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The problem is that the JavaScript console and your app use different profiles (credential and region) and therefore DynamoDB local will create separate database files for them. By using the -sharedDb flag when starting the local DynamoDB, a single database file will be shared for all clients.

From the [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html):

> -sharedDb — DynamoDB Local will use a single database file, instead of using separate files for each credential and region. If you specify
>   -sharedDb, all DynamoDB Local clients will interact with the same set of tables regardless of their region and credential configuration.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that the JavaScript console would use a different db was not at all clear from that doc line for me.

Comment: You can use a docker container with volumes setted - `docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -v /tmp/data:/data/ dwmkerr/dynamodb -dbPath /data/`

[run-amazon-dynamodb-locally-with-docker](http://www.dwmkerr.com/run-amazon-dynamodb-locally-with-docker/)

**Note**: You need to setup a *Access Key Id* on Dynamo JS shell to:
[DynamoDB Local loses tables?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=553723)

Comment: There is an official docker image available from Amazon now on Docker hub. https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I saw this earlier

Comment: I personally had control over everything, so it was better for me to keep the in-memory tables and just make sure that regions and credentials were identical in all test fixtures. Though, I did have to run tcpdump on port 8000 before I found the last set of bad credentials.

Answer (score 50):

Those who are using [the official](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/use-amazon-dynamodb-local-more-easily-with-the-new-docker-image/) [DynamoDB Local Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/) should use this line to start it to enable `sharedDb`:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory -sharedDb
```

The original [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) used by the image can be seen in `docker inspect amazon/dynamodb-local` output and are:

```
"Entrypoint": [
    "java"
]
"Cmd": [
    "-jar",
    "DynamoDBLocal.jar",
    "-inMemory"
]
```

So we basically need to copy them and add `-sharedDb`.

Comment: dear god you are a life saver!

Comment: well what can i say, i owe you like 40 hours of life

Comment: I am facing this error 'Unrecognized option: -inMemory '

Comment: Alternatively, make sure all your clients use the same access key ID and the right region.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CircleCI, here is what your executor should look like:

```yaml
# using service containers on CircleCI
# https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/databases/
executors:
  with-dynamodb:
    docker:
      # image used to install source code,
      # run our server and run Cypress tests
      - image: cypress/base:14.17.3

      # image used to run Dynamodb in a separate container
      - image: amazon/dynamodb-local:1.17.0
        # HERE IS THE IMPORTANT PART
        command: ["-jar", "DynamoDBLocal.jar", "-inMemory", "-sharedDb"]
```

The `command` option allows you to override the default `CMD` in the Dockerfile, pointed out by @madhead.